# False Speech for forming a non exist Buddhism Club

Tags: doubt

Dad admitted due to covid. Me, mum and Dad stayed in the same house so me and mum were close contact yet need to quarantined. I was tested negative with no syndrome for all 10 days quarantine.

Mum had flu syndrome in the day 3 of quarantine. She was reluctant to perform PCR swab test because it's quite expensive. Mum can be quite stubborn too most of time. I believe most old folks will have this problem.

I can't slowly or patiently talk to her too face to face as she doesn't even wear a mask neither i need a PPE suit nor special wearing to communicate with her for safety purpose.

I hire another care taker that found online, pay him and request him to pretend as Buddhism community club to offer her free PCR swab test. Mum only accept in this way. I can't delay this as mum start developing psychosis mental illness too during this quarantine period. She will only feel much better when receiving free stuffs. If she found positive then need send to quarantine center immediately. At least me will not be infected. If all down, then who is gonna work and feed food to us?

Mum indeed recovering well with mild syndrome. She is much happier too after this non exist Buddhism club care taker exist, received a lot free stuffs and start to accept Buddhism teaching too.

Q) Did i committed a false speech fault by getting a "non exist" Buddhism club to offer help? What will be the punishment in this case base on Buddhism teaching ?

Comment: That's ok. You and your hired caretaker can become a small unregistered Buddhist club of your own, providing support and care for your mother. In this case then, you would be speaking the truth. If you feel that you still need to punish yourself, please see [this video](https://youtu.be/mAvaDXittW4?t=2242) - Ajahn Brahm prescribed 50 strokes of the cat.

Comment: I really like that answer.  Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

'Yes but the end goal is something good. I think that would overweigh the bad here'

As such ideas would be an.opening for what ever excuse, that is why the precepts are laid out simply and clear by the Sublime Buddha. Wrong speech stays wrong speech. Whether one does wrong for ones mother, friends, the Ling, even the Buddha, for oneself..., the effects of such kamma (deeds) wouldn't change. There is no such as rightly doing wrong and there are most alternatives ass well, ways not require unskilled deeds.

And as good householder sees right here: this going into defilements ideas, at least, doesn't make him free of remorse and doubtless in regard of his blameless virtues. So always acting on simple and clear kusala Dhamma to avoid such and keep grow open, let on walk on.

In case trapped in a fault, confessing, after seeing it, toward a admirable friend who hasn't same fault, and resolve not tp do it again, would free him to walk on, get out of the hole and the deeds ripping would be easier taken.

Best is always to try the good way based on faith out to know what what abstain and letting go (of unskillful) means. Then one might experience the different in of being debtless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Buddhist and have taken on the precepts then you broke the 4th one. The precepts are not a reward/punishment system.

Comment: Yes but the end goal is something good. I think that would overweigh the bad here.

Comment: I thought he was asking if making something up was lying.  I didn't see it as question about whether the end justifies the means.

Answer (score 0):

**Did i committed a false speech fault by getting a "non exist" Buddhism club to offer help?**

I'm not sure what you mean by "false speech" but here is how [the Vinaya](https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/Ebooks/BMC1&2_200826.pdf) defines "a deliberate lie":

> 1. Intention: the aim to misrepresent the truth; and
> 2. Effort: the effort to make another individual know whatever one
>    wants to communicate based on that aim.

You might also want to read the sutta quotes chosen on the subject of [Right speech](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html).

**What will be the punishment in this case base on Buddhism teaching ?**

I don't know. I guess it's easy to imagine possible consequences, including "feeling remorse"; and possibly "not being trusted in future if you develop a reputation as a liar."

Also read [MN 61](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html).

For example perhaps you want to be good, or want to be seen as good -- therefore you *say* that you did something good -- but, if you say it as a lie instead of doing it, then one of the harmful consequences is that the good thing isn't done! Similarly if you say you stopped doing something bad, but haven't: then the bad thing isn't stopped. In short, any "training" or "progress" (in the path) doesn't happen, only continued samsara.

Looking at the Noble Truths, "suffering" arises with a craving for things to be other than as they are -- which is closely associated with (i.e. more-or-less the same as the motive for) lying.

When there's a temptation to tell a falsehood, perhaps it's worth considering, "this is something that I wish were true" -- for example, "wouldn't it be good if there were a Buddhist community club" -- and then instead of telling an easy lie, maybe act to make that wish a reality.

Or perhaps something else, like understanding why it's not a reality.

---

That said, the example that you gave seems to be a form of lying that's similar to the [Parable of the burning house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upaya#Parable_of_the_burning_house) -- i.e. attracting her to do something by telling her of something "shiny" or attractive although unreal. Note that's quoting the Lotus Sutra, I think that different schools of Buddhism may differ on whether that kind of falsehood might be considered skilful, ethical.

Theravada Buddhists (monks especially) might be careful not to lie, even as a joke.